# Auto-Layout 3 views in a container. So if the container shrinks, only one subview at a time shrinks

Tags: ios, macos, interface-builder, autolayout

Here is my container view with 3 subviews
The top view will always be 200 tall
The middle view will be between 0 (default) and 70 tall
the bottom view will be at least 150 tall

EDIT: My current relevant constraints:

```
Top of topSubview equal to top of superview
bottom of topSubview equal to top of middleView
bottom of middleSubview equal to top of bottomView
bottom of bottomSubview equal to bottom of superview

Topview height >= 200
middleView height <= 70
bottomView height >= 150
```

[image]

I have been trying to set this auto-layout but I can't seem to make it happy.

If I increase the size of the container horizontally, all the views resize with it.  perfect.

When I increase vertically, I would like the middle view to expand to 70, and then the bottom view to increase from 150->whatever

When I decrease vertically, I would like the bottom view to shrink to 150, then the middle view to shrink to 0

But when I do this, the views just don't stick together and resize in the IB.

[image]
[image]

Does anybody have any advice for me?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't appear to be pinning the bottom and tops of the views to each other. You'll need to first start there if you don't want overlapping views.

Comment: I added an edit with my current constraints.  I believe they are right, but I still can't get the views to move around in IB automatically when I resize

Comment: Yeah, Interface builder has been terrible about automatically moving views in Xcode 6. It used to 'just work'. I'd recommend trying it out with live simulation instead.